# useEffect unable to invoke function directly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

VersionA: `useEffect(() => doRequest(), []);`

VersionB:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  doRequest();
}, []);
```

I've always thought both the version are exactly the same, where VersionA is a shortcut and VersionB allowing you to do more than single command within the inline function.

However when I use VersionA, I'm hitting `TypeError: func.apply is not a function`, threw by NextJS

[image]

If I use syntax of VersionB, everything working fine. Wondering if anyone faced this before?

**UPDATES**
The full code for my component

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import useRequest from '../../hooks/use-request';
import Router from 'next/router';

export default () => {
  const { doRequest } = useRequest({
    url: '/api/users/signout',
    method: 'post',
    body: {},
    onSuccess: () => Router.push('/'),
  });

  useEffect(() => doRequest(), []);
  return <div>Signing you out...</div>;
};
```

Comment: Can we have your component code ?

Comment: This seems like a NextJS problem, both approaches, although semantically different, do not throw errors in React. It seems like NextJS expects you to always return a function inside `useEffect`

Comment: @ethane How did you conclude that? NextJS doesn't tamper with what `useEffect` does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not exactly the same.

```
useEffect(() => doRequest(), []);
```

In this case your callback will implicitly return the value that `doRequest()` returns. A `useEffect` callback can only return a function (for cleanup of the effect) or `undefined`. You can use that syntax if `doRequest` either returns nothing (meaning `undefined`) or a cleanup function.

*EDIT*: As noted by @3limin4t0r `() => fn()` is the same as `() => { return fn(); }`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  doRequest();
}, []);
```

By having a function body and not explicitly returning something your function implicitly returns `undefined` which is fine if there is nothing to cleanup.

Comment: @Isaac Are you aware that the function provided to `useEffect` can optionally return a cleanup function? And are you aware that arrow functions that only consist of a single statement without a body implicitly return the result of that statement?

Comment: ^ `() => fn()` is the same as `() => { return fn(); }` See the [arrow function documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Syntax).

Comment: @3limin4t0r: Thanks for the link! Now I get it

Answer (score 0):

This is written about in the official docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup).

Any function returned from `useEffect` is used for "cleaning up".

In your first example `doRequest` returns something other than `undefined`, which React will try to call as a function to "clean up" when the component unmounts.

Example of `useEffect` with a clean up function:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  // This is a "clean up" function
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  };
}, []);
```

Example of `useEffect` without a clean up function. Note this is bad as the listener will still fire after the component unmounts.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
}, []);
```